# How to program programmable keyboards

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I've a programmable keyboard which i connected with my computer (Windows 10) using USB cable. My Windows recognizes it and is listed as a Programmable Keyboard in the Control Panel.

When i click on the keys, the keyboard plays a buzzer sound but nothing happen on the screen (neither in text areas). I guess need to program it but i don't know how and found no software for it.

Here's the keyboard: [Keyboard](https://rstechdz.com/img/p/5/3/8/538-thickbox_default.jpg) and here's it is in my control panel: [My Control Panel](https://i.ibb.co/DfR0Q0r/control-panel.png)

I would like later on to program it in Java or any other langage, but for now i believe at least if i could interact with it it would be a whole achievement.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many different methods, all of which depend on the model of keyboard to program. Since the manufacturer's website link you provided has no support information for that model, I'd suggest you [contact them directly](http://rstechdz.com/index.php?controller=contact).

Comment: Thank you, i'll do that